# In python, how do I map an iterable to an iterable?

Tags: python, stream, functional-programming, iterator, iterable

I have an iterable -- that is, something which responds to `__iter__` and which can be  iterated over lazily, *multiple times* using a new fresh iterator each time.

I want to *map* this to another *iterable*, which can also be iterated over multiple times, but without bringing the whole collection into memory.

`map` doesn't work -- it returns a list, so brings the whole dataset into memory.

`itertools.imap` also doesn't work -- it takes an *iterable* but returns a one-shot *iterator*.

What I'm looking for is a set of itertools-like combinators which operate at the level of iterables. Only at the final stage, when I'm consuming the end result, do I want a single-shot iterator object, so I don't really understand why `itertools` returns them rather than returning e.g. some kind of MappedIterable.

Pointers anyone? Or is this somehow heretically non-Pythonic?

Comment: What's wrong with a generator expression? Or `itertools.izip()`? This all very much depends on what you actually want to *do* with the values.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what kind of processing you expect to do with your two iterators.

Comment: A generator expression is a one-shot object, not an iterable collection.

Comment: Could you post the code of your lazy, multiple iterable? An maybe a use-case and expected and observed behaviour?

Comment: But `iter(youriterable)` is a one-shot iterator as well. All iterators are one-shot, and that is by definition.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! I want an iterable, not just an iterator, as the result of this map operation. I think I should probably give an example of what this would look like, coming up!

Comment: The problem here is that either you need to store the results of the function, in which case, you need to put the whole iterable in memory, or you need to recompute all the values on every iteration over the iterable, in which case, returning a multiple-use iterable gives a misleading impression of the costs of repeated iteration. If you want to iterate repeatedly, why not recreate the iterator the same way you originally got it?

Comment: {{{class MappedIterable(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, map_function):
        self.underlying_iterable = iterable
        self.map_function = map_function

    def __iter__(self):
        iterator = iter(self.underlying_iterable)
        return (self.map_function(x) for x in iterator)
}}}

Comment: @Matt: All that an iterable's `__iter__` method does is return an iterator for that object. The *iterator* is always one-shot. Python will produce that iterator time and Python will do so under the hood for certain operations. If you want a more complex operation, then you can encapsulate that operation *in a generator expression, a generator function or a factory function producing the iterator*. That's then repeatable too.

Comment: @Matt: So what is wrong with that setup? You could make it a factory function too; `def mapped_iterable(iterable, map_function): return (map_function(x) for x in iterable)` (No need to call `iter()` as `for` does this for you).

Comment: For the specific case of `itertools`, that library is designed to work on arbitrary iterables, so it can't rely on the inputs being multiple-use. If it returned some sort of MappedIterable, then in all likelihood, iterating over the result twice still wouldn't work, since the input iterator(s) would be exhausted.

Comment: Another way to put it: I want something which behaves like `itertools.imap`, but takes a https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable and returns a https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable

Comment: @Matt: But there an exponential number of ways to produce such iterables. And most of the time you need to produce that transformation just once, not repeatedly over the same pre-determined iterable(s). It is trivial to build the latter on top of the iterable tools we have now. There is no generalization here, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think we may be talking at cross purposes to some degree. What I want is quite standard in the collection libraries of other languages which have distinct interfaces for Iterable vs Iterator (like Scala's for example). Mapping an Iterable returns a mapped Iterable, preserving the convenient property that the iterable is able to be iterated over lazily multiple times. Mapping an Iterator returns an mapped Iterator. Seems to me it ought to be quite possible and elegant in Python too but it seems perhaps by historical accident, the `itertools` module wasn't implemented this way.

Comment: Ah, I guess perhaps because in Python Iterators implement __iter__ too, so it's hard to know if it's a true Iterable or not, is that what you meant? Perhaps with this abstract baseclass stuff in Python 3 it would be easier to tell Iterables (https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable ) from iterators?

Comment: @Matt: I think Python's abc's don't help here because `collections.abc.Iterable` is a base class of `collections.abc.Iterator`, in line with the usual Python definitions of the words. Every iterator is an iterable, but you want a function that returns an iterable plus an additional guarantee for which there is no abc. There's nothing "between" Iterable and Sequence. Of course you can invent one of your own, but nobody else's iterables will implement it so you have to register them yourself if you find any.

Comment: I guess in duck-typing style, you could identify multi-shot iterables as supporting `__iter__` but not `__next__`. I think it'd be possible to come up with a general implementation which wraps the iterable interface (`__iter__`) and also wraps `__next__` if it finds that too. In the latter case it could leave `__iter__` as returning `self`, although that might just be an optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools` is reasonably simple, it mostly (entirely?) doesn't do different things depending on the iterable/multiply-iterable/sequence-ness of its input. `imap` doesn't know or care that you've passed it an iterable that *happens* not to be an iterator.

```
class MyMap(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *iterables):
        self.func = func
        self.iterables = iterables
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(itertools.imap(self.func, *self.iterables))
```

Or something along those lines. I haven't tested it.

It's difficult (impossible?) to do this automagically, since the Python iterator protocol doesn't tell you whether or not an iterable can be iterated more than once. You can assume that if `iter(i) is i` then it *can't*, but I don't think you can safely assume that if `iter(i) is not i` then it *can*.

Basically an iterable that can be iterated multiple times (analogous to what C++ calls a ForwardIterator as opposed to a mere InputIterator) is not a concept commonly demanded by Python programmers AFAIK. So I think you might have to write your own wrapper for itertools.

Comment: You don't need `iter()` in the `__iter__` method; normally `__iter__` is *called by `iter()`*.

Comment: Thanks -- yeah that's what I want, I guess I was hoping there might be an `itertools`-like library of combinators which work like this somewhere which people have standardised though. I guess not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: right, because `itertools.imap` returns an iterator already. It's just habit really, if I'm writing an `__iter__` function that delegates to something else I stick the call to `iter()` in there whether it's needed or not, in order to "prove" that I'm returning an iterator. Before developing that policy I would sometimes accidentally leave it out when needed and return an iterable. It's possible that I'm now smart enough not to need the policy, but I guarantee nothing.

Comment: @Matt: well, give it more than half an hour before concluding there isn't, but based on past performance if Martijn doesn't know about it then it can't be *very* commonly used. My use/knowledge of Python isn't very community-minded, so "AFAIK" in my answer is, "I've vaguely searched for this distinction before and haven't found it".

Comment: Accepting this. For the record an "iterable that can be iterated multiple times" is a very useful concept when you're writing multi-pass algorithms which learn from large datasets. I suppose for most Python uses though, it's acceptable to just bring it into memory, so it hasn't been a priority. If I need this a lot more times I might make a little library which mirrors `itertools` and returns iterables. Cheers

Comment: @Matt: right, Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm could be a motivating example. Or more generally, a version of `itertools.tee` that doesn't use additional memory for multiply-iterables. There's still a restriction, that an iterator taken from a multiply-iterable is just singly-iterable. So it's still not going to come out looking quite like (for example) C++ iterator categories.